# Angular - Argument of type 'IContact[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IContact[]'

Tags: angular

In Angular-12 project I have this JSON API Response:

```json
    {
      "message": "Employee Detail.",
      "error": false,
      "code": 200,
      "results": {
        "employee": {
            "id": 8,
            "first_name": "JONAH",
            "last_name": "YAKUBU",
            "other_name": "AKWETEY",
            "employeecontacts": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "phone_type_id": 2,
                    "employee_id": 8,
                    "phone_number": "014566778",
                    "is_primary_contact_number": 1,
                    "phonetypes": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "type_name": "Arena",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "phone_type_id": 3,
                    "employee_id": 8,
                    "phone_number": "016766709",
                    "is_primary_contact_number": 0,
                    "phonetypes": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "type_name": "Office",
                    }
                }
            ]
          }
      }
    }
```

Interface:

```js
    export class EmployeeResponse {
      results!: { employee: IEmployee; };
    }

    export interface IEmployee {
      id?: number;
      first_name?: string;
      other_name?: string;
      last_name?: string;
      employeecontacts?: IContact[];
    }

    export interface IContact {
      id?: number;
      phone_number: string;
      phone_type_id?: number;
      phonetypes?: {id:number,type_name:string};
      is_primary_contact_number?: boolean;
    }
```

service:

```js
    getEmployeeById(id: number): Observable<EmployeeResponse> {
      return this.http.get<EmployeeResponse>(this.api.baseURL + 'employees/fetchbyid/' + id, this.httpOptions);
    }

    public updateEmployee(id: number, employee: IEmployee): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.put(this.api.baseURL + 'employees/update/' + id, employee, this.httpOptions);
    }
```

component:

```js
_id!: number;
contactInfoForm!: FormGroup;
contactdata!: IEmployee;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this._id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.updateContact();
  this.loadContactById();
}

loadContactById() {
  this.employeeService
    .getEmployeeById(this._id)
    .subscribe((data: EmployeeResponse) => {
      this.contactdata = data.results.employee;
      this.contactInfoForm.patchValue({
        first_name: this.contactdata.first_name,

      });
    });
  this.contactInfoForm.setControl('contacts', this.SetExistingContacts(this.contactdata.employeecontacts));
}

SetExistingContacts(contactSets: IContact[]): FormArray {
  const formarray = new FormArray([]);
  contactSets.forEach(c => {
    formarray.push(this.fb.group({
      phone_number: c.phone_number,
      phone_type_id: c.phone_type_id,
      is_primary_contact_number: c.is_primary_contact_number
    }));
  });
  return formarray;
}

updateContact() {
  this.contactInfoForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    first_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    contacts: this.fb.array([
      this.addContactFormGroup()
    ])
  });
}

addContactFormGroup(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    phone_type_id: ['', Validators.required],
    phone_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]],
    is_primary_contact_number: ['']
  });
}

public addContactButtonClick() {
  const contacts = this.contactInfoForm.get('contacts') as FormArray
  contacts.push(this.addContactFormGroup())
}

get contacts() {
  return this.contactInfoForm.controls['contacts'] as FormArray;
}

getContactFormGroup(index: number): FormGroup {
  return this.contacts.at(index) as FormGroup;
}
```

I am tying to load data into the Dynamic FormArray and then update it.

I got this error from the component:

```
Argument of type 'IContact[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IContact[]'.
```

Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IContact[]'.ts(2345)

And this line is highlighted:

> (this.contactdata.employeecontacts));

in:

> this.contactInfoForm.setControl('contacts', this.SetExistingContacts(this.contactdata.employeecontacts));

How do I resolve the error and then update the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IEmployee` interface has an **optional** property:

```js
employeecontacts?: IContact[];
```

So it's expected to have that error message. Typescript doesn't know if it's going to be `undefined` or an actual value.

Try the following:

```js
 this.contactInfoForm.setControl(
      'contacts', 
      this.SetExistingContacts(this.contactdata.employeecontacts!) //note the ! at the end
 );
```

Also, I noticed the line of code where the error is, it should be inside the `subscribe` function. You are storing data into `this.contactdata` and you trying to get `employeecontacts` outside, it doesn't have any data yet.

```js
loadContactById() {
  this.employeeService
    .getEmployeeById(this._id)
    .subscribe((data: EmployeeResponse) => {
      this.contactdata = data.results.employee;
      this.contactInfoForm.patchValue({
        first_name: this.contactdata.first_name,
      });
     
     this.contactInfoForm.setControl(
        'contacts', 
        this.SetExistingContacts(this.contactdata.employeecontacts)
     );
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely working under `strict-null-checks`.

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html

> in this example, both xPos and yPos are considered optional. We can choose to provide either of them, so every call above to paintShape is valid. All optionality really says is that if the property is set, it better have a specific type.

> We can also read from those properties - but when we do under strictNullChecks, TypeScript will tell us they’re potentially undefined.

So your property `employeecontacts?: IContact[]` is treated as `employeecontacts: IContact[] | undefined` under the hood.

This is where `strict-null-checks`'s assignment rules come in.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html

Under strict null checks, `null` and `undefined` are only assignable to themselves and `any`. In the first list of examples provided by the above link, your case would be the equivalent to the line `x = y; // Error`, just with your `IContact[]` type instead of `number`;

There's a couple solutions:

1. Turn off `strict-null-checks`, which will allow you to assign `null` and `undefined` to any type.
2. Cast your your call, i.e. `this.SetExistingContacts(this.contactdata.employeecontacts as IContact[] | undefined));` or `this.SetExistingContacts(this.contactdata.employeecontacts!));`
3. Change the parameter type for `SetExistingContacts` to `IContact[] | undefined`

Answer (score 0):

As extension of @Andres answer, you can use [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operator to check `this.contactdata.employeecontacts` have the value.

When it has no value (`null`, `undefined`), it will assign `[]` (empty array) for the argument of `SetExistingContacts` method.

```js
this.contactInfoForm.setControl(
  'contacts',
  this.SetExistingContacts(this.contactdata.employeecontacts || [])
);
```

Meanwhile, you need to move the above lines in the `subscribe` event, otherwise `this.contactdata.employeecontacts` will not have value from the response.

```js
loadContactById() {
  this.employeeService
    .getEmployeeById(this._id)
    .subscribe((data: EmployeeResponse) => {
      this.contactdata = data.results.employee;
      this.contactInfoForm.patchValue({
        first_name: this.contactdata.first_name
      });

      this.contactInfoForm.setControl(
        'contacts',
        this.SetExistingContacts(this.contactdata.employeecontacts || [])
      );
    });
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j79qdd)